# How do I get the minimum of certain elements of an array with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dijkstra

I need to know the minimum element of a data for certain elements in an iterating array.

I have three array dist, Q and vertex:

```
dist = [  0.  inf  inf  inf  inf]
vertex = [2 4 5 7 8]
Q = [2 4 5 7 8]
```

The dist array are the vertex values. Each iteration Q decreases and dist has different values. For example:

First iteration:

```
dist = [  0.  inf  inf  inf  inf]
vertex = [2 4 5 7 8]
Q = [2 4 5 7 8]
```

Second iteration:

```
dist   = [  0.  4.  2.  2.  1.]
vertex = [2 4 5 7 8]
Q      = [4 5 7 8]
```

Third iteration

```
dist =   [ 0.  4.  2.  2.  1.]
vertex = [2 4 5 7 8]
Q =      [4 5 7]
```

The idea is to find the minimum of **dist** but only of the available values of **Q** in **vertex**. In the first iteration the minimum is 0 because they are all in **Q**. In the second iteration the minimum 1, that is to say the 8 in **vertex**, because in **Q** there is not the 4 that has value 0 in **dist**.

This is a part of the Dijkstra algorithm in which it finds the minimum of the values of Q. In pseudocode it would be:

```
u ← vertex in Q with min dist[u]    // Node with the least distance
```

I'm just using the Numpy library.

My solution so far:

```
    min = np.inf
    u = 0
    for q in Q:
        if dist[self.vertex == q] <= min:
            min = dist[self.vertex == q]
            u = q
```

Comment: Sure, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little trick: add ∞ if the vertex is not in `Q`:

```
>>> dist =   [ 0.,  4.,  2.,  2.,  1.]
>>> vertex = [2, 4, 5, 7, 8]
>>> Q =      [4, 5, 7]

>>> vertex_mask = np.array([0 if x in Q else float('inf') for x in vertex])
>>> np.min(vertex_mask+dist)
2.0
```

Comment: Although I'm afraid it has the same algorithmic complexity

Comment: turn `Q` into a `set()`, and the complexity will go from O(m*n) to O(m log n)